# How to properly catch FileNotFoundException when using PhysicalFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download

I'm having this code in a controller method;

```
try
{
    return PhysicalFile("c:\temp\my-non-existing-file.txt", "text/plain");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

However, the catch clause is not run in this case, but instead a `500 Internal Server Error` is returned to the browser. Having the developer error page active, it shows that a `FileNotFoundException` was indeed thrown, but the call stack shows it comes from a middleware.

```cs
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\temp\my-non-existing-file.txt'.
File name: 'c:\temp\my-non-existing-file.txt'
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.PhysicalFileResultExecutor.GetFileInfo(String path)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.PhysicalFileResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, PhysicalFileResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.PhysicalFileResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at MyApp.Authorization.AuthorizationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<---->b__1>d.MoveNext() in ---:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MyApp.Authorization.AuthorizationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<--->b__1>d.MoveNext() in ---:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Can someone explain how to properly handle this case and return `404 Not Found` instead?

**Update:** Added full stack (with some name cleaning)

Comment: I suspect your controller isn't being called at all - there's no sign of it or the PhysicalFile constructor in the stack trace... it looks like the static file middleware is trying to handle it, not your controller.

Comment: Exactly, but how are you suppose to handle this case if you don't want to return 500 but instead a more proper 404?
Do I explicitly have to check if the file exists before returning?

Comment: can you share your controller-action and the URL you call? as @JonSkeet said, StaticFileMiddleware catches your URL. Did you debug? Does it hit the controller?

Comment: The presence of static-files in the stack-trace is a little misleading - it's just passing the request on through the pipeline which does actually end up in MVC. The problem here is that you're constructing a new `PhysicalFileResult`, which doesn't *execute* until later in the MVC pipeline and so runs *outside* of your `try`/`catch` pair.

Comment: @ibrahimozgon This code is directly within the controller action. Putting a breakpoint inside `try` and `catch` will only hit in the `try`. Btw, added the full stack. Had omitted a few lines that I didn't see any value in exposing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @KirkLarkin correctly pointed out, the file is not resolved until later, when the response is being spooled, which happens after your action has already exited. As such, you can't catch that exception here. There's probably something you could do with custom middleware or exception handlers, but honestly, why not just do the following instead:

```
var filename = "c:\temp\my-non-existing-file.txt";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
{
    return PhysicalFile(filename, "text/plain");
}
else
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

It's always better to proactively check conditions, rather than relying on catching exceptions. Excessive reliance on exception handling can degrade your app performance.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed this would be the best solution after all. Just wanted to know if there's something I'm missing :)

Comment: That's [only a mitigation, that probably works most of the time](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2009/12/10/the-file-system-is-unpredictable.html) - but not the solution we really want. - [The sad case of `File.Exists` is a common topic.](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1032679477032042496)